# Conditional IF() statement problem, not returning desired value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently writing a program in excel that will return a value based on user input. The current formula has 5 different return options which are returned based on the selection of a number by the user. I use the IF() statement embedded into more IF() statements to account for multiple input options. However, when I go to enter in a number beyond the range of the first IF() statement, I am getting 0 even though it should be a different number.

For the code below, C30 is the input cell and it should return .15 if I was to enter 25.

```
=IF(C30<20, 0.35, IF(20<C30<40, 0.15, IF(40<C30<60, 0, IF(60<C30<80, -0.1, IF(80<C30, -0.2, 0)))))
```

From the logic statements, it should be returning .15, but all I am getting is 0.

Comment: Try replacing `20<C30<40` with just `C30<40`and replace `60<C30<80` with just `C30<80`.

Comment: If you go to "Formulas" > "Evaluate Formula" and step through - you should see the issue on the second or third click of "Evaluate"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel does not use `20<C30<40` it would be:

```
AND(20<C30,C30<40)
```

But you can shorten this with a simple MATCH and CHOOSE:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(C30,{0,20,40,60,80}),0.35,0.15,0,-0.1,-0.2)
```

If you really want a nested if there is no need for the extra tests:

```
=IF(C30<20,0.35,IF(C30<40,0.15,IF(C30<60,0,IF(C30<80,-0.1,-0.2))))
```

IF will resolve sequentially and short circuit as soon as it finds the first TRUE, so it does not need the other logic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the logic that you have used to evaluate whether `C30` falls within a range of numbers.

`IF(20<C30<40,...)` will *not* check whether `C30` is in the range of 20 through 40.

Instead, use `AND(cond1, cond2, ...)` to check whether the values are within the range:

```
IF(AND(C30 > 20, C30 < 40), ...)
```

Comment: I've always been fond of the form `IF(C30=MEDIAN(20,C30,40), ...)` for this

Answer (score 0):

Replace terms like:

```
20<C30<40
```

with:

```
AND(20<C30,C30<40)
```

etc.